# java: justifying existence of different Exception classes

Tags: java, exception

1. Assume during app development you created 5 different exception classes to use throughout your code.
2. You then noticed, that all of these exceptions are handled in the same way. Say all you do for all 5 exceptions, when they're caught, you log  a message. There's nothing else you're doing (or can do) to recover from the exception being thrown.

The question is:

Is the same handling a good enough reason to replace all 5 different exception classes with one. Or is there some real value in having 5 different exceptions because their names (the names of the exception classes) can help to understand the problem and ease debugging or any other reason....

Or to rephrase it:

When you create a new exception class in your code, is it when you can see that there can be a **unique handling** of this exception in the code or is it to **aptly describe** the problem with the exception class name?

Comment: Depends on the Priciples your team arranged. Using KISS they are obsolete. Self-Documentation Prinzip may need the diversifications. What principles has your Team?

Comment: @PeterRader there is no way you can say they violate KISS without more information about the classes. As always with design, the only general answer starts with "it depends."

Comment: @TheThom violate!=obsolete. From KISS PoV, i think they are obsolete as long as the are *handled the same way*. But you are right: *it depends* on other principles the team use. Thats why i wrote a comment, not an answer. I think too, a answer must respect other principles the team/project use.

Answer (score 0):

If the exceptions are handled in the same way and they have the same fields, they might as well be one.

However, there is some merit to having 5 different exception classes for 5 different cases. You named one of the advantages: It can help to understand the code (self-documenting code).

Another advantage is that later on you (or someone) might decide to introduce different handling of some of these exceptions in the future. Having different kinds of exceptions thrown beforehand makes implementing the new exception handling a lot easier.

That said, a danger is that you'll often have copy-pasted, redundant code in the exception class itself, which is a disadvantage you'll have to weigh against the advantages.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case,you could just have one custom exception which could be handled *generally*. While throwing that exception, you could send a *specific String message* mentioning the reason / place of *actual* exception*. Let the *appropriate* caller handle this exception.

Advantage : Prevents multiple exception classes (and hence their bookkeeping overhead).

Answer (score 0):

You have already identified one reason why having multiple exceptions can be better.  It potentially makes debugging easier.

If they are checked exceptions, then a second reason for having multiple exceptions is that when you declare a method as throwing a specific exception (rather than a general one), it makes it easier for someone coding against the API to understand what can happen.

Finally, if you have already created and used the exceptions (consistently), then *keeping* them gives you the option of handling the exceptions differently at some point in the future.  For example, if your application's requirements change.

---

> When you create a new exception class in your code, is it when you can see that there can be a unique handling of this exception in the code or is it to aptly describe the problem with the exception class name?

When I am designing an application, I create a new exception whenever there is an "error condition" whose semantics aren't adequately<sup>1</sup> described by an existing exception.  How the exceptions are going to be handled (the same or differently) is simply not a consideration ... for when *I* am designing the code.

<sup>1 - Obviously, what is *adequate* is a matter of opinion.  I certainly wouldn't create a different exception for every fine semantic distinction.  That is where the `message` attribute comes into play.</sup>

Comment: Interesting points. The only thing I disagree with is the part 'keep it, cause you may have need to handle them differently in the future'. It's against YAGNI principle.

Answer (score 0):

Different exceptions provide more information to the handler. This is normally a good thing if not abused.

The most important thing about your exceptions that you didn't mention is do they extend a common base class? If so, then your catch and throws clauses are still simple even though you provide more detail.

Usually, when I build a system from the ground up, I have at most two base exceptions that all other exceptions extend--a checked exception and an unchecked exception. This way my classes can catch generic exceptions just to stop exceptions generated by our code and can be as specific as I like to slice for problems to gain granular solutions.

So, I think both to handle an exception differently is equally important to creating more information in your code. I think the redundant code is worth both of these reasons.

Comment: Good point on common super class to simplify handling. It is in place.

Comment: @artur Thanks. I would appreciate an upvote or being marked as the answer if you are happy with my advice.